# Youtube Comment Search

Tags: search, comments, youtube

Digging around on youtube and flickr's APIs, I noticed Flickr allows you to poll all recent comments (once per hour).  Youtube however only allows pulling all comments for a specific video.  I'm curious if anyone has any clever ideas on a way to poll+cache or search site-wide youtube comments.  I don't know what the comments per second rate is on youtube but I'm guessing it's insane.